# Script is not activating the options

Tags: bash, terminal, options, url

I'm making a script to open url by terminal and when typing:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

## origin: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/script/Abrir-arquivos-em-nova-aba-no-Firefox
##
### Se quizer que o novo link abra em nova janela digite New-Window; Se quizer em novo aba, digite New-Tab entre as apas abaixo. O padrão é New-Tab.

N=0
J=0
A=0
L=0

TAB="--new-tab"

WINDOW="--new-window"

TAB_KTERMINAL="konsole --new-tab -- bash -c"
TAB_GTERMINAL="gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c"

LYNX="$(which lynx)"

FIREFOX="$(which firefox)"

## Opções de --new-tab e --new-window OK
CHROME="$(which google-chrome)"

## URL default
HOME_PAGE="http://www.google.com"

function help(){
echo -e "\n\e[1;31mUsage\033[1;32m: \033[1;34m${0} \033[1;35m(\033[1;32m-f \033[1;31m | \033[1;32m-g\033[1;35m) (\033[1;32m-t \033[1;31m| \033[1;32m-w\033[1;35m) (\033 [1;32m--url\033[1;35m)\033[1;34m=\033[1;37m\"\033[1;32mwww.shellscript.com.br\033[1;37m\"
\n\033[1;35m(\033[1;32m-f\033[1;35m) \033[1;34m= \033[1;37mto open with mozilla-firefox
\033[1;35m(\033[1;32m-g \033[1;31m| \033[1;32m--ch\033[1;35m) \033[1;34m= \033[1; 37m to open with google-chrome
\033[1;35m(\033[1;32m-t\033[1;35m) \033[1;34m= \033[1;37mto open a new tab in the open browser
\033[1;35m(\033[1;32m-w\033[1;35m) \033[1;34m= \033[1;37mto open a new browser window
\033[1;35m(\033[1;32m--url\033[1;35m) \033[1;34m= \033[1;37m\"\033[1;32mwww.shellscript.com.br \033[1;37m\"\n"

  exit 0
}

OPTS=$(getopt -a -n ${0} -o f,g,t,w,h --long url:,ch:,help -- "$@")

eval set -- "${OPTS}"

if [ $# -lt 3 ]; then
  help
else

  while :; do
    case "$1" in
    -f)
      N=1
      NAVEGADOR="${FIREFOX}"
      shift 2
      ;;

    -g | --ch)
      N=1
      NAVEGADOR="${CHROME}"
      shift 2
      ;;

    -t)
      A=1
      NEWTAB="${TAB}"
      shift 2
      ;;

    -w)
      J=1
      JANELA="${WINDOW}"
      shift 2
      ;;

    --url)
      L=1
      URL="${2}"
      shift 2
      ;;

    -h | --help)
      help
      shift
      ;;

    --) #Skip
      shift
      break
      ;;

    esac
  done
fi

echo
echo "(($N && $A)) && ${NAVEGADOR} ${NEWTAB} ${HOME_PAGE}"
echo
echo "(($N && $J)) && ${NAVEGADOR} ${JANELA} ${HOME_PAGE}"
echo
echo "(($N && $A && $L)) && ${NAVEGADOR} ${NEWTAB} ${URL}"
echo
echo "(($N && $J && $L)) && ${NAVEGADOR} ${JANELA} ${URL}"
echo
```

When running the command:

```
./url -f -t --url="www.shellscript.com.br"
```

It should show:

```
((1 && 1 && 1)) && /usr/bin/firefox --new-tab www.shellscript.com.br
```

But it is showing:

```
((1 && 0 && 1)) && /usr/bin/firefox www.shellscript.com.br
```

---

When running the command:

```
./url -f -w --url="www.shellscript.com.br"
```

It should show:

```
((1 && 1 && 1)) && /usr/bin/firefox --new-window www.shellscript.com.br
```

But it is showing:

```
((1 && 0 && 1)) && /usr/bin/firefox www.shellscript.com.br
```

---

When running the command:

```
./url -g -t --url="www.shellscript.com.br"
```

It should show:

```
((1 && 1 && 1)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome --new-tab www.shellscript.com.br
```

But it is showing:

```
((1 && 0 && 1)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome www.shellscript.com.br
```

---

When running the command:

```
./url -g -w --url="www.shellscript.com.br"
```

It should show:

```
((1 && 1 && 1)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome --new-window www.shellscript.com.br
```

But it is showing:

```
((1 && 0 && 1)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome www.shellscript.com.br
```

---

and I'm also trying to understand how to design the code for it to open only what was passed to the command if you type:

example:

```
./url -f -t
./url -f -w
./url -g -t
./url -g -w
./url -g -t --url="www.shellscript.com.br"
./url -g -w --url="www.shellscript.com.br"
```

When running the command:

```
$ ./url -g -t
```

The output is:

```
((1 && 0)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome  http://www.google.com

((1 && 0)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome  http://www.google.com

((1 && 0 && 0)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome  

((1 && 0 && 0)) && /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

When running the command:

```
$ ./url -f -t
```

The output is:

```
((1 && 0)) && /usr/bin/firefox  http://www.google.com

((1 && 0)) && /usr/bin/firefox  http://www.google.com

((1 && 0 && 0)) && /usr/bin/firefox  

((1 && 0 && 0)) && /usr/bin/firefox
```

it only opens one instance of the browser instead of opening several.

Comment: If you insert `set  -x` as the second line of your script, you'll turn ON tracing, and see what your script does. Also, always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shift by two in several places where the option does not have an argument. Only the `--url` option has an argument, so only that one should do `shift 2`.

Comment: If I don't use shift 2 it doesn't show anything and it's in an infinite loop how can I solve these problems?

Comment: Use just `shift` to consume one command line argument. You need to learn what `shift` does to the command line. Just copying and pasting some code and then modifying it without understanding what it does (which seems to have happened with the command line processing loop) will not get you far ;-)

Comment: I just used shift and it keeps looping infinitely

Comment: Show your code. You're still doing something wrong. And please heed the advice by @waltinator to use `-x` for debugging.

Comment: I removed the shift 2 and restarted the computer and it ran correctly I don't understand why.